# How to wrap SVG content?

Tags: wordpress, svg

I want to use SVG in my WordPress site. The content of this SVG will be changed and I want it to be dynamic:

Here is my code:

```
<div style="height:60px;" class="gmr_main_page_svg_div">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="6773 1755 730 81" style="height:60px;" class="gmr_main_page_svg">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        clip-path: url(#clip-iPhone_6_7_8_1);
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #0652fd;
      }

      .cls-3, .cls-4 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #0652fd;
      }

      .cls-3 {
        stroke-width: 3px;
      }

      .cls-4 {
        stroke-width: 4px;
      }

      .cls-5 {
        fill: #fff;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: IRANSans-Bold, IRANSans;
        font-weight: 700;
      }

      .cls-6 {
        fill: rgba(255,255,255,0);
      }
    </style>
    <clipPath id="clip-iPhone_6_7_8_1">
      <rect x="6773" y="1755" width="900" height="81"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="iPhone_6_7_8_1" data-name="iPhone 6/7/8 – 1" class="cls-1">
    <rect class="cls-6" x="6773" y="1755" width="730" height="81"/>
    <g id="Group_2830" data-name="Group 2830" transform="translate(6586 1751)">
      <path id="Path_3672" data-name="Path 3672" class="cls-2" d="M1319.065,1810h189.586v-69.9h-131.61Z" transform="translate(-593 -1732)"/>
      <path id="Path_3673" data-name="Path 3673" class="cls-3" d="M1319.065,1810h189.586v-69.9h-131.61Z" transform="translate(-600 -1736)"/>
      <line id="Line_108" data-name="Line 108" class="cls-4" x1="728" transform="translate(187.5 76.5)"/>
    </g>
    <text id="خدمات_ما" data-name="خدمات ما" class="cls-5" transform="translate(7376 1779)"><tspan x="130.443" y="22">ویژگی‌های طراحی لوگو</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>


</div>
```

Here is my a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7yc2fL1n/).

I used some image to SVG converters and this is the output of my image.

Comment: Do you the upload the svg file in wordpress??

Comment: no, i use visual composer's raw html and insert my svg code into the page

Comment: Can you tell exactly what you need, Now you can svg image at frontend, what next do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code on functions.php file,

Please check below code -

```html
function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
 $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
 return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
```

Try it!!

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what does this snippet do?

Comment: You can upload the SVG file and SVG content on your website.